# creating a mesos cluster with many nodes without public ips

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I have a running Mesos master node with a public IP on a KVM based Virtual machine on the Cloud, to which I can connect other agents across the network. I have one machine in my lab which I have public ip and I can connect it to the Mesos master. I have used below commands to start master and slaves into the cluster.

> sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --advertise_ip=129.xxx.110.yy
>
> sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=129.xxx.110.yy:5050 --advertise_ip=129.xxx.111.zz

Now the problem is I have many other machines in my lab, which does not have public ip addresses.

How can I connect them to the Mesos master?

Comment: What do you get if you try to run mesos agent on machine without public IP without specifying advertise ip? `sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=129.xxx.110.yy:5050`

Comment: if I run without advertise public ip, then I can see the agent getting added to mesos master under the deactivated slaves. And we can not submit jobs, jobs are getting failed. Mesos master reporting:  "Transport endpoint is not connected". I suspect its not actually connecting to the master.